# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter error while rendering partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http, razor

I am basically trying to refresh my partial view on some clickEvent() and I am doing an Ajax POST for that. My View looks something like following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#employeeGrid").click(function() {
            var grid = $("#employeeGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var currentSelection = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
            alert(currentSelection.Id);
            $.ajax({
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: 1 }),
                url: "/Employee/ShowEmployeeDetails",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    // refreshes partial view
                    $('#EmployeeDetails').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
      </script>
```

And my controller looks like following:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ShowEmployeeDetails(int id)
        {

            List<EmployeeLOAHistory> employeeLoaHistoryList = new List<EmployeeLOAHistory>
            {
                new EmployeeLOAHistory
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                    EndDate = DateTime.Now
                },
                new EmployeeLOAHistory
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                    EndDate = DateTime.Now
                }
            };
```

Also, when I trace my request in the Firebug, it also shows that the id was posted correctly and it looks like folloing:

```
{"id":1}
```

However, response stream tells completely different story and it looks like following:

```
<title>The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ShowEmployeeDetails(Int32)'

                return PartialView("_EmployeeDetails");
            }
```

I have no idea why is that. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to remove `JSON.stringify()` - just `data: { id: 1 },`

Comment: Can you please turn it into an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to stringify the json object. Change the ajax option to

```
ajax({
    data: { id: 1 }, // change this
    url: '@Url.Action("ShowEmployeeDetails", "Employee")', // recommended
    .....
```